# Expo SQLite I can't fetch items in database

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

Hi i'm trying to install database on my react native app with expo-sqlite. And when i try to fetch programs i got a warning and no other log. I tried to insert first but i think i couldnt do it either. At first actually dbinit returns a response when initalizing but after that nothing works. dbinit Response below:

{
"version": "1.0",
"_db": {
"_closed": false,
"_name": "deep_config.db"
},
"_txnQueue": {
"length": 0
},
"_running": false,
"_currentTask": null
}

The warning:

```
LogBox.js:148 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
WebSQLTransaction {
  "_complete": true,
  "_error": null,
  "_running": false,
  "_runningTimeout": false,
  "_sqlQueue": Queue {
    "first": undefined,
    "last": undefined,
    "length": 0,
  },
  "_websqlDatabase": WebSQLDatabase {
    "_currentTask": null,
    "_db": SQLiteDatabase {
      "_closed": false,
      "_name": "deep_config.db",
    },
    "_running": false,
    "_txnQueue": Queue {
      "first": undefined,
      "last": undefined,
      "length": 0,
    },
    "closeAsync": [Function bound close],
    "deleteAsync": [Function bound deleteAsync],
    "exec": [Function bound exec],
    "version": "1.0",
  },
}
```

my database code :

```js
function openCB(db: any) {
    console.log("SQL executed");
    console.log(db);
}

const database = SQLite.openDatabase(
    "deep_config.db",
    "1.0",
    "Test Database",
    200000,
    openCB
);

export const dbInit: any = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS programs (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            programName TEXT NOT NULL,
            daysOfWeek TEXT NOT NULL,
            startHours TEXT NOT NULL,
            startMinutes TEXT NOT NULL,
            workingHours TEXT NOT NULL,
            workingMinutes TEXT NOT NULL,
            triggerTime TEXT NOT NULL,
            cableDirection TEXT NOT NULL
            );`,
                [],
                (res) => {
                    resolve(res);
                },
                // @ts-ignore
                (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
        });
    });
    return promise;
};


export const fetchPrograms = (id: "*" | number) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `SELECT * FROM programs WHERE id = ${id};`,
                [],
                (_, res) => {
                    resolve(res);
                },
                // @ts-ignore
                (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
        });
    });
    return promise;
};
```